# Search for Value in Oracle SQL amongst other text

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking to find out how I can write a query that will allow me to search a column that has other text around the text I am looking for.

My table currently looks like this:

```
NAME    CODES        REQUIRED_CODE
------  -----------  -------------
Humpty  AB@CD@EF@GH  IJ
Minnie  AB@CD        CD
Mickey  ZA@HP@YP     HP
```

What I want to do is to add a True/False Column that will search for the required code within the codes field but I am not sure how I can go about writing this.

REQUIRED

```
NAME    CODES        REQUIRED_CODE  TRU
------  -----------  -------------  -----
Humpty  AB@CD@EF@GH  IJ             False
Minnie  AB@CD        CD             True
Mickey  ZA@HP@YP     HP             True
```

Would appreciate it if somebody could advise how I go about writing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read about [LIKE](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/like.php) condition.

Comment: Just a tip, format the sample data into proper colums, to make it easier to read for anyone who wants to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a trigger that will fire on insert and on update that will maintain the value of the boolean column.

If your table's DDL looks something like this:

```
create table tab (
    codes         varchar2(30),
    required_code varchar2(3),
    code_found    varchar2(3)
);
```

Then something like this trigger DDL will probably work for you.

```
create or replace trigger tab_code_found before insert or update 
   on tab for each row
begin
   if :new.codes like '%' || :new.required_code || '%' then
      :new.code_found := 'YES';
   else
      :new.code_found := 'NO';
   end if;
end;
```

Instead of the like operator, you can use this predicate which might consume fewer CPU cycles:

```
   instr(:new.codes, :new.required_code) > 0
```

Comment: Or simply create a view.

Comment: @jarlh I had in mind indexing, which a view won't address.

Comment: That's true. What about a materialized view? (I don't know Oracle.)

Comment: You can index a materialized view pretty much like any other table. But MV refreshes are almost always a significant concern.

Comment: Why a trigger? The OP is looking to **write a query** - using the base data. The extra column appears only in the result of the query. This has nothing to do with what happens or what should happen when DML transactions occur against the base table.

Comment: Because of "want to do is to add a True/False Column".

Comment: "add a column" doesn't mean "to the base table." In this context it means "to the result of the query" (to the `SELECT` clause).

Comment: That's not the way I read it. If he had reputation=1, then I would have asked for clarification.